# webpack error bundle.js package with a PdfCreator

Tags: webpack, sharepoint, bundle

please anyone has the same issue ?
already tried ng build, npm run build

tried to reinstall the packages and node module
still facing the same issue

```
Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./lib/webparts/pdfCreator/PdfCreatorWebPart.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js' in 'C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/webparts/pdfCreator'
resolve 'pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js' in 'C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/webparts/pdfCreator'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/package.json (relative path: ./lib/webparts/pdfCreator)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/package.json (relative path: ./lib/webparts/pdfCreator)
    resolve as module
      C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/webparts/pdfCreator/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/webparts/pdfCreator/lib doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/webparts/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/webparts/lib doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    
      looking for modules in C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib
        using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
          using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/package.json (relative path: ./lib/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:/Users/admin/Developer/node_modules
        No description file found
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        No description file found
        no extension
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:/Users/admin/Developer/node_modules/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js doesn't exist
        .js
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:/Users/admin/Developer/node_modules/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.js doesn't exist
        .json
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          C:/Users/admin/Developer/node_modules/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json doesn't exist
        as directory
          C:/Users/admin/Developer/node_modules/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js doesn't exist
      looking for modules in C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/node_modules
        using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/node_modules/pdf-creator/package.json (relative path: ./dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js)     
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              resolved symlink to C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js
                using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/package.json (relative path: ./dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js)
                  no extension
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js doesn't exist
                  .js
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.js doesn't exist
                  .json
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json doesn't exist
                  as directory
                    C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js doesn't exist
              C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/node_modules/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              resolved symlink to C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.js
                using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/package.json (relative path: ./dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.js)
                  no extension
                 
              C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/node_modules/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              resolved symlink to C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json
                using description file: C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/package.json (relative path: ./dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json)
                  no extension
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json doesn't exist
                  .js
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json.js doesn't exist
                  .json
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json.json doesn't exist
                  as directory
                    C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json doesn't exist
              C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/node_modules/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/node_modules/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js doesn't exist
[C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/lib/webparts/pdfCreator/node_modules]

[C:/Users/admin/Developer/node_modules/package.json]

[C:/Users/admin/Developer/pnp/ng-pdf/PdfCreator-spfx/node_modules/pdf-creator/dist/PdfCreator/bundle.js]
 @ ./lib/webparts/pdfCreator/PdfCreatorWebPart.js 14:0-47
```

I tried to do the gulp bundle --ship

and faced this error, already tried to update the packages and reinstall the package file.

did the package-solution
the package extracted normally but appears to be an issue when i implemented

here is the package details

```
{
  "name": "pdf-creator-spfx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "preversion": "node ./tools/pre-version.js",
    "postversion": "gulp dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.4.0",
    "@pnp/pnpjs": "^2.15.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "pdf-creator": "file:../PdfCreator"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.4.1",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "gulp-sequence": "1.0.0",
    "spfx-uifabric-themes": "^0.8.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: it looks like webpack can't find pdf-creator, whatever it is.. is it installed?

Comment: yes its installed

Comment: Is pdf-creator an npm module? Or what is it? in your package.json it looks differently from all other packages

Answer (score 0):

```
"pdf-creator": "file:../PdfCreator"
```

seems like you are trying to use a custom developed package which won't work like this for SPFx.
I think you should use the `Library` component which you may generate using yeoman @microsoft/sharepoint generator.
[image]

then you may just reference it in `package.json` of your webpart just like any other package like

```
"pdf-creator": "0.0.1"
```

then if you want to locally test it you have to create a link between the library and the package like

- bundle and build the solution of your library running `gulp bundle --ship` and then `gulp build`
- run the command `npm link`
- go to the webpart folder
- run the command `npm link <library name like pdf-creator>`
- modify the 'config/serve.json' file and specify the initialPage with your local workbench
- test the webpart locally running `gulp serve`

after that if you want to deploy it to your tenant you need to:

- go to library folder
- in the command-line run:

  - `npm install`
  - `gulp bundle --ship`
  - `gulp package-solution --ship`
  - Add to AppCatalog and deploy (check option to make this solution available to all sites)
- go to webpart folder
- in the command-line run:

  - `npm install`
  - `gulp serve`
  - `gulp bundle --ship`
  - `gulp package-solution --ship`
  - Add to AppCatalog and deploy

You may use [this sample from the PnP webpart repo](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-save-to-onedrive-app-personal-folder) for more details as it also is based on two SPFx components (webpart + library)